# RIA IDE - Visual Studio 2010, FlashBuilder and ExtJS Designer

Tags: c#, php, apache-flex, silverlight, extjs

I trying to decide whether we went to Flex, Silverlight or even ExtJS. There is one variable missing so that we can make the decision and this is about Visual Studio.

With Silverlight, it looks like if I want a "drag and drop" approach to build my interface I would need Expression Blend to do that.

So the basic question here is: Does Visual Studio 2010 will come with some sort of Silverlight component palet so that you can easily drag and drop it on your interface like you would do with WPF, etc? I don't wanna use Blend - is way too much for what we need - taking the "coding XAML" by hand is out of question as well.

Comment: Too broadly phrased in my opinion. We do not know your project and cannot tell which IDE would be appropriate for you or your dev team. If you didn't even settle on a language yet, how are we supposed to give you any helpful suggestions, besides stating: I use Software X because I like it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gordon.
I agree - its too abroad...
I can only say its a web application and we decide to go for RIA.
There is no specific language related thing that could drive us to one or another.

I think the only specific question there is: Does Visual Studio 2010 comes with a "drag and drop silverlight components on an interface" thing?

I was also in the hope of getting some tips from people with experience in those environments/languages/technologies.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I tried to rephrase the question based - hope this is more specific now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is Yes. There is a decent'ish drag drop xaml design part to VS2010.

However I would strongly recommend you look at Blend when doing UI work. RIA to me often means that the applications experience is "Rich", and Blend makes a lot of things trivial compared to VS. Plus it's part of most MSDN subscriptions these days, so cost is less of an issue.